# GROUP BY function ret

Tags: mysql, data-analysis

| start | end | category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022:10:14 17:13:00 | 2022:10:14 17:19:00 | A |
| 2022:10:01 16:29:00 | 2022:10:01 16:49:00 | B |
| 2022:10:19 18:55:00 | 2022:10:19 19:03:00 | A |
| 2022:10:31 07:52:00 | 2022:10:31 07:58:00 | A |
| 2022:10:13 18:41:00 | 2022:10:13 19:26:00 | B |

The table is sample data about trips

the target is to calculate the time consumed for each category . EX: category A = 02:18:02

1st I changed the time stamp criteria in the csv file as YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS to match with MYSQL, and removed the headers

I created a table in MYSQL Workbench as the following code

```
CREATE TABLE trip (
  start TIMESTAMP,
  end TIMESTAMP,
  category VARCHAR(6)
    );
```

Then to calculate the consumed time I coded as

```
SELECT category, SUM(TIMEDIFF(end, start))  as length
FROM trip
GROUP BY CATEGORY;
```

The result was solid numbers as A=34900 & B = 38000

SO I added a convert, Time function as following:

```
SELECT category, Convert(SUM(TIMEDIFF(end, start)), Time)  as length
FROM trip
GROUP BY category;
```

THE result was great with category A =03:49:00 , but unfortunately category B= NULL instead of 03:08:00

WHAT I'VE DONE WRONG , what is the different approach I should've done

Comment: First of all, you mentioned wanting "time consumed for each trip" and you end up with time consumed for each category. Which one is it you want?

Comment: I need to know the total time consumed for each category

Comment: You can't use sum on times.  Sum seconds, then convert to time.  But be aware a time can't be 839 hours or more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it as follows :

This is useful to Surpass MySQL's TIME value limit of 838:59:59

```
SELECT category, 
CONCAT(FLOOR(SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, `start`, `end`))/3600),":",FLOOR((SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, `start`, `end`))%3600)/60),":",(SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, `start`, `end`))%3600)%60) as `length`
FROM trip
GROUP BY category;
```

This is to get time like 00:20:00 instead of 0:20:0

```
SELECT category, 
CONCAT(
    if(FLOOR(SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, `start`, `end`))/3600) > 10, FLOOR(SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, `start`, `end`))/3600), CONCAT('0',FLOOR(SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, `start`, `end`))/3600)) ) ,
    ":",
    if(FLOOR((SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, `start`, `end`))%3600)/60) > 10, FLOOR((SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, `start`, `end`))%3600)/60), CONCAT('0', FLOOR((SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, `start`, `end`))%3600)/60) ) ),
    ":",
    if( (SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, `start`, `end`) )%3600)%60 > 10, (SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, `start`, `end`) )%3600)%60, concat('0', (SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, `start`, `end`) )%3600)%60))
    ) as `length`
FROM trip
GROUP BY category;
```

Comment: thanks a lot , it is a wonderful approach either , although it seems petty complex

Comment: Can you vote up if you like it and maybe accept it If you see it useful for you

Answer (score 0):

You'd calculate the length for each separate trip in seconds, get sum of the lengths per category then convert seconds to time:

```sql
SELECT category, SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, `end`, `start`))) as `length`
FROM trip
GROUP BY category;
```

If SUM() exceeds the limit for TIME datatype (838:59:59) then this MAXVALUE will be returned.

---

For the values which exceeds the limit for TIME value use

```sql
SELECT category,
       CONCAT_WS(':',
                 secs DIV (60 * 60),
                 LPAD(secs DIV 60 MOD 60, 2, 0),
                 LPAD(secs MOD 60, 2, 0)) AS `length`
FROM (
     SELECT category, SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, `end`, `start`)) AS secs
     FROM trip
     GROUP BY category
     ) subquery
;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help , but I am working with way too big data , It gives the max number 838:59:59

Comment: For Instance , in the original CSV file when I calculate that length for each category it reaches 180736:03:00, How could I calculate it in SQL

Comment: @Maysara ? Does updated query cannot solve?

Comment: I think hours should be div 60*60, not 24?

Comment: @ysth Oops.. you're correct, I'll edit shortly... done. Thank you!